# Random forest for forecasting univariate time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, random-forest, univariate

I read few articles on random forest and its implementation in various fields. But I hardly found any literature on its implementation on forecasting univariate time series.

- Can it be used for forecasting univariate time series?
- If yes, how?
- If no, why?

Comment: It really depends on the nature of your time series, and what your 'modelling', i.e. what you feed to the random forest. If you think finance, I would daresay no. These are at a first and good approximation random walks... If the time series describe a very deterministic phenomenon, it could be.

Comment: @mic: Actually I was searching for literature related to Finance. Thanks for your response. Cleared one of my confusions. 
But can it be used if I am trying to classify the trading signals based on derivatives of stock price data i.e 3-days MA, RSI etc?

Comment: It would be nice if you could comment on use of bagging for univariate time series forecasting in context of Finance.